# print-break-inside stretching items to the entire page on IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, printing, angular-material

I am trying to print angular material table without page breaks inside rows so I am using style.

```
.mat-row {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Everything works fine on Chrome and Firefox but IE11 sometimes will stretch single row to the entire page height.

It's very large project so I cannot really provide any plunkr, but it look's like this: [image: error]

Does anyone else encountered such a bug and know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

here is the rule I use on a aria compliant layout.

```
*[role=main] section,form{ page-break-before:always;-webkit-break-before: always;break-before:always }
```

see https://caniuse.com/#search=page-break-inside

for a table of cross-browser support.

What does the Emulation tab of your IE dev tool say? viz: which IE emulation mode are you using... If this is an internal/intranet site, IE may be using a lower emulation version.